# Yup - run async validation test only on value change

Tags: reactjs, yup

Yup async validation test is getting called multiple times. Is there any way to call test only when there is change in value or prevent validation check for same value

```
    const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
    zipCode: yup.string().required()
        .test('invalidZip', 'ZipCode must be valid', (value, context) => {
            /**
             * api call to validate zip code
             * this is getting called multiple times even though there is no change in 
             * zipCode.
             * I want to run this test only if there is change in value
             */
            return new Promise.resolve((resolve) => Utils.validateZipCode(value, resolve));
        })
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Sadly yup runs validation on all fields in schema no matter which one was changed. It is especially painful when you do remote calls in your yup tests (for instance REST request). This is known issue, see this thread for many workarounds https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/512 . The one that I used is based on answer by `thenameisflic` and goes something like this:

```
const cacheTest = (asyncValidate: (val: string) => Promise<boolean>) => {
    let _valid = false;
    let _value = '';

    return async (value: string) => {
        if (value !== _value) {
            const response = await asyncValidate(value);
            _value = value;
            _valid = response;
            return response;
        }
        return _valid;
    };
};

const actualValidityTest = cacheTest(
    (value: string) => new Promise(
        (resolve) => yourTestLogic()
    )
);
```

and plug it in like this:

```
.test(
    'test_name',
    'some message',
    shopNameValidityTest
)
```

The main idea of the fix is that you cache previous value passed to test as well as previous validation result. If value did not change then return previous validation result. However, if verified value changed then run actual validation and cache result.

One nice thing about this solution is that it is pretty generic, you can wrap any of your tests in `cacheTest` and avoid unnecessary validations.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/512

mahj0ubiwael's answer here. **document.activeElement.id**. get the field id and use it in your

```
    .test(email,"err string",() => {
if(document.activeElement.id === "email"){
// Validate here
}
})
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33501705)